# Random command not found error in shell script

Tags: shell, scripting

I'm having an issue where when I run my script it randomly will out put command not found errors for commands I'm not running. for example I will get

```
{: command not found
```

when I run this function

```
function createBucket() {
    bucket=$1
    aws s3api create-bucket --bucket $bucket --region $region || $(errorExit "Could not create bucket.")
    aws s3api put-bucket-versioning --bucket $bucket --versioning-configuration Status=Enabled || $(errorExit "Could not enable versioning.")
}
```

And all the commands in the function will run fine but it'll still spit out these errors. This makes it tough to handle errors when false positives are emitted like this.

Comment: ShellCheck points out that you probably didn't intend to have `$(..)` around `errorExit "Could not create bucket."`. Since you do it here, you've probably done it other places too, and if you do it around anything returning JSON you'll get the error you describe. It's hard to say without enough code to reproduce though.

Comment: That would do it. I removed all the lines with `$()` and that solved the problem. Thanks!